# Compare and combine two files (shell script)

Tags: shell

I have two input files.

I need to compare file1 and file2 and combine the lines that have the same *first field* in both files. (The rest of the line can be ignored the rest of the line.)

Ideally, I'd like the fields in the output file to be pipe separated.

I'm thinking a simple shell script is all that I need.

file1

```
0001|14
9934|3
4555|33
```

file2

```
0001|coffee|grocery store
0003|gasoline
0005|pickup sticks
9934|protein bars
4555|car
```

Desired output:

file3

```
0001|14|0001|coffee|grocery store
9934|protein bars
4555|33|4555|car
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your desired output is inconsistent. The first and third lines include the "key" column again, and includes all additional columns from both files. The second only contains the key and the additional column from file2. How should a solution determine which of those two patterns to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a {print a[$1], $0}' f1 f2
0001|14|0001|coffee|grocery store
9934|3|9934|protein bars
4555|33|4555|car
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this command and am getting the following errors:
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: This is tested on BSD and gnu awk. Can you check your awk version and let me know

Comment: I'm not really sure how to check. I ran what /usr/bin/awk and what /bin/awk, which returned SunOS 5.10 Generic 127884-01 Oct 2007

Comment: Oh SunOS seems to be using very old version of awk. I read somewhere that there is nawk and awk both available in SunOS. But I have no way to test this on SunOS as I only have Mac and Linux hosts available.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I don't get an error when I run nawk but nothing happens either. Oh well. I'll keep plugging along.